# Matching key value pair from a python dictionary gives absurd results

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have created a python dictionary for expanding acronyms. For example, the dictionary has the following entry:

```
Acronym_dict = {
     "cont":"continued"
}
```

The code for the dictionary lookup is as follows:

```
def code_dictionary(text, dict1=Acronym_dict):

for word in text.split():
   for key in Acronym_dict:
        if key in text:
            text = text.replace(key, Acronym_dict[key],1)
return text
```

The problem is that the code is replacing every string that contains substring 'cont' with continued. For example, continental is getting replaced by 'continuedinental' by the dictionary. This is something that I don't want. I know I can add space before and after each key in the dictionary but that will be time-consuming as the dictionary is quite long. Any other alternative?? Please suggest.

Comment: `text.replace` replaces exactly what it finds.  If you want to replace acronym `cont` set the key of the dictionary key with spaces on either side of the word like this: ` cont ` and the value should also have spaces ` continued `.

Comment: Why value should also have spaces?

Comment: That will allow you to isolate and match the acronym.   `replace` replaces exactly what it finds and it has no concept of words.   So, if you want to find usage of the acronym you have to isolate it.   I am assuming a space may help isolate it but if you have a situation like ` cont.` or if the acronym was at the start of a line or end of a line my suggestion will not work.   To be able to really catch it I think you will have to use a regular expression to search and replace the acronym instead of the simple `.replace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few solutions:

1. Use regular expressions to find isolated words using `\b` (word break):

```
import re

Acronym_dict = {
     r'\bcont\b':'continued'
}

def code_dictionary(text, dict1=Acronym_dict):
    for key,value in dict1.items():
        text = re.sub(key,value,text)
    return text

s = 'to be cont in continental'
print(code_dictionary(s))
```

```
to be continued in continental
```

2. If you don't want to change your dictionary, build the regular expression.  Note `re.escape` makes sure the key doesn't contain anything treated differently by a regular expression:

```
import re

Acronym_dict = {
     'cont':'continued'
}

def code_dictionary(text, dict1=Acronym_dict):
    for key,value in dict1.items():
        regex = r'\b' + re.escape(key) + r'\b'
        text = re.sub(regex,value,text)
    return text

s = 'to be cont in continental'
print(code_dictionary(s))
```

```
to be continued in continental
```

3. Fanciest version, does all the acronym replacement in one call to `re.sub`:

```
import re

Acronym_dict = {'a':'aaa',
                'b':'bbb',
                'c':'ccc',
                'd':'ddd'}


def code_dictionary(text, dict1=Acronym_dict):
    # ORs all the keys together, longest match first.
    # E.g. generates r'\b(abc|ab|b)\b'.
    # Captures the value it matches.
    regex = r'\b(' + '|'.join([re.escape(key)
                               for key in
                               sorted(dict1,key=len,reverse=True)]) + r')\b'
    # Replace everything in the text in one regex.
    # Uses a callback to look up the value of the acronym.
    return re.sub(regex,lambda m: dict1[m.group(1)],text)

s = 'a abcd b abcd c abcd d'
print(code_dictionary(s))
```

```
aaa abcd bbb abcd ccc abcd ddd
```

Comment: I am using suggestion 2. Thanks, Mark!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

Acronym_dict = {
     "cont":"continued"
}

def code_dictionary(text, dict1=Acronym_dict):
    # for word in text.split():
   for key in Acronym_dict:
      text = re.sub(r'\b' + key + r'\b', Acronym_dict[key], text)
   return text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = '''
abcd cont ajflkasdfla cont.
cont continental afakjsklfjakl jfalfj asl cont fjdlaskfjal fjal
cont
'''

    print(text)
    print('--------------------')
    print(code_dictionary(text))
```